# How to find intersection of k arrays in Mongodb such that the time complexity of the code is very low?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, intersection

How to find intersection of k arrays in Mongodb such that the time complexity of the code is very low?
Actually, $setIntersection is used for intersection of two arrays only.

Comment: You'll have a better time with redis.

Comment: When using MongoDB, that sort of this is probably best handled at application-level. Unless maybe you have to find the "intersection" of many arrays scattered among a large number of documents ?

Comment: I think this question lack of a concrete example. As far as I am concerned, it is hard to understand what you need _exactly_.

Comment: arr1=[A,B,C,D], arr2=[A,B], arr3=[A,B,C]  Intersection=[A,B]    Suppose, you have k arrays as a value in collections. How to find the intersection of k-arrays simultaneously.